# any synonym suggestion for "commonly identified"?

Tags: synonyms

Is there any idea how to say on another way "Peter is 'commonly identified' as Mark." Any synonym suggestion?

Comment: What are you describing? That he is taken to be somebody he isn't, that he pretends to be somebody he isn't, or simply that he goes by a different name? Even after answering that, what criteria do you have for choosing one answer over another? (Just asking for a list of synonyms isn't useful.)

Comment: "Peter" goes by a different (Mark) name

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on intent.

If you mean people commonly see Peter and think he's Mark, I'd suggest **mistaken for**.
As defined by [thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mistaken+for):

> 2. To recognize or identify incorrectly: He mistook her for her sister.

If you mean that Peter actually goes by or responds to the name Mark, perhaps [a.k.a. (also known as)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/a.k.a.):

> abbreviation for also known as

Answer (score -2):

We can call " ika" for the commonly identified